# matplotlib on ubuntu, no output

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu

New to python here.  Using python 3.9.7 on Ubuntu 20.04.3, matplotlib 3.4.3, running a script that seems to run ok but doesn't give any output.  I've played with installing "tkAgg" and think it is there but still nothing.  This is the code in question that appears to run but nothing appears on screen.

I've also looked for simple test examples to test my install but not found anything simple, suggestions?  Where should I start to debug?  Thx. J.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for i, (image, label) in enumerate(train_ds.take(9)):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.title(int(label))
    plt.axis("off")
```

Comment: where are you running your code?

Comment: I'm running it from an "an inferior python shell" within emacs.  I got something to run by adding the code "plt.show()" to end, which seems to have been omitted in the code example!  This should produce a single image of 9 different pictures but when I run it from the shell is produces 9 individual figures.  However if I save the .py file and run it via python3.9 file.py  it produces 1 figure with 9 pictures in it, as it should.  Any idea how to correct?  Thx. J

Comment: Sounds like path issues?